# how to restrict text typing and extra text adding but not italic bold highlighting so that user cannot add text but that can bold text

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

i want users to bold, highlight text only but not text typing
i want to disable text typing from ckeditor 5
i am using ckeditor 5 with react.js to build writing plateform but i want from users to use bold, highlight, comment features and stop users from typing extra text

```
 toolbar: [
                  "undo",
                  "redo",
                  "heading",
                  "bold",
                  "italic",
                  "link",
                  "bulletedList",
                  "|",
                  "imageUpload",
                  "insertImage",
                  "insertImageFromUnsplash",
                  "blockQuote",
                  "code",
                  "codeBlock",
                  // "insertTable",
                  "mediaEmbed",
                  "removeFormat",
                ],
    config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }#something like this
]
```

i tried to remove all plugin from toolbar but it did not stop from adding and typing extra text
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LocBL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try 'restricted editing mode'

```
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    plugins: [ Bold, RestrictedEditingMode, ... ],
    toolbar: [ 'bold', '|', 'restrictedEditing', ... ],
    restrictedEditing: {
        allowedCommands: [ 'bold' ]
    }
} )
```